# STM32G030J6M6 Debug issue

Tags: stm32, st-link, stm32g

I just bought two STM32G030J6M6 and solder it on my custom board . here is schematic
[image]

in STM32CubeIde I'm just setting `SWDIO/SWCLK` pins.. nothing else, Also I updated STLink's firmware to `V2.J39.S7`(I'm using chinese STLink device).

So when I'm trying to debug , then debugger can't find device.
Also tried `STM32CUbeProgrammer`, same `Can't find STM32Device`,
Same thing with `STLINK-Utility`, I tried a lot of configurations:

```
Connect Under Reset,
Hardware Reset
Normal
```

but no result.
Then I tried to manually flash it via `st-flash` command and I got this

```
st-flash 1.6.1-262-g0eebc9a
2022-03-24T11:40:14 WARN common.c: unknown chip id! 0x3748
Failed to connect to target
```

BTW voltage is `+3.29V`

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Given SWCLK shares function with UART1_TX and BOOT0, there has to be something in documentation about how to flash it, did you check MCU datasheet?

Comment: Found a thread discussing that on github, very same error message, someone solved it by connecting under reset: https://github.com/stlink-org/stlink/issues/1012#issuecomment-751650320

Comment: Yes I know , datasheet says: "The boot pin is shared with a standard GPIO and can be enabled through the boot selector option bit", but how can I enable it when debugger can not see device at all?

Comment: I doubt this is all flashing-related information in the entire datasheet. It's not about boot0 only. SWCLK too.

Comment: @Ilya how can I change FLASH and other registers when the ST-LINK can not see the device physically? I already saw that link, did not help.

Comment: I mean I can not flash anything on my STM32G0 MCU.

Comment: I don't mean change flash or registers. I mean flashing. Programming. Writing program into flash. You're not the first and not the last who has to do it with this MCU. There has to be more than 1 sentence related to it in the datasheet. Also, I did send you a link to a possible solution. Please, try it and report back.

Comment: @Ilya don't try to be smart *ss. I read datasheet and a lot of sentences before write my problem here. So if you can not say anything else rather than "datasheet" you can just *hut your mouth.

Comment: I don't understand why you are salty, but please try the possible solution I have found specifically for you. It helped someone, it may help you.

Comment: Why would anyone bother messing around with ST-Link clones when the OEM ones are so cheap? Toss that thing in the bin and go purchase a real ST-Link. If you still have problems, then at least I would be slightly more interested in trying to help.